# Given a polynomial function as a string, return the first derivative as a string

Tags: python, string, derivative

I'm attempting to create a simple derivative calculator function that takes a polynomial function as string, and returns the first derivative as another string. I'm a beginner and am completely lost on how to start.

```
def derivative(str):


derivative("3*x^2 + 4*x - 22") # Should return 6*x^1 + 4*x^0 - 0
```

If someone could help me get started with this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: If it's a polynomial break it up into what it actually is. `ax^a1 operator bx^b2 operator ... constant`. Many different ways to parse through it including regular expressions.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.  Best of all, each tutorial will teach you a collection of related techniques, rather than merely solving the immediate problem.  Symbolic differentiation is covered well in many places on line; please do that research and make a reasonable attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's symbolic library [`sympy`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html) can take care of [converting a string](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html) to a symbolic expression and of taking [derivatives](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html). Note that Python uses `**` for `power`, while `^` is only used for the boolean exclusive or.  [`convert_xor`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html#parsing-transformations-reference) takes care of converting the `^` to a power.

Here is some sample code to get you started and experimenting.

```py
from sympy import sympify, Derivative
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr, standard_transformations, convert_xor

def derivative(str_expr):
    transformations = (standard_transformations + (convert_xor,))
    expr = parse_expr(str_expr, transformations=transformations)
    return str(Derivative(expr).doit())

print(derivative("3*x^2 + 4*x - 22"))
print(derivative("sin(x/cos(x))"))
print(derivative("exp(asin(x^2)/sqrt(x))"))
print(derivative("LambertW(x)"))
print(derivative("erf(x)"))
```

Output:

```
6*x + 4
(x*sin(x)/cos(x)**2 + 1/cos(x))*cos(x/cos(x))
(2*sqrt(x)/sqrt(1 - x**4) - asin(x**2)/(2*x**(3/2)))*exp(asin(x**2)/sqrt(x))
LambertW(x)/(x*(LambertW(x) + 1))
2*exp(-x**2)/sqrt(pi)
```